# Y in transform.position has different value in inspector than in code

Tags: unity, c#, transformation

I've got very simple code:

```cs
private void StepButtonClicked(int stepIndex) {
    _scenarioManager.SetActiceStepIndex(stepIndex);
    var position = _steps[stepIndex].transform.localPosition;
    var difference = _stepsPointer.transform.position - position;

    Debug.Log(differencePosition.x);

    _stepsPointer.transform.position = new Vector3(
        x: position.x,
        y: 1f,
        z: 0);
}
```

But I don't understand why the value of `position.y` shows as -662 in the inspector instead of 1 as set in code.

[image: Inspector screenshot showing wrong value]

Can you tell me why is this happening? X position is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

The inspector does not show you `transform.position` (the object's location in world space).

It shows you `transform.localPosition` (the object's position in its parent object's coordinate system).

For objects at the root level of the hierarchy, with no parent object, these are equivalent, so you might have gotten used to thinking of them interchangeably.

Here `StepsViewPointer` is a child of `Viewport`, so when you set `transform.position`, Unity works out what `localPosition` the object would need to have relative to `Viewport` in order to sit at the given position in world space.

If you want to set the location relative to the parent, set `localPosition` directly, rather than asking Unity to convert from a world space position to parent space automatically. Or for a `RectTransform` in a UI canvas, it often helps to work with `anchoredPosition`.

You should also make sure not to combine/subtract positions in different coordinate spaces, like where you're computing `difference` as a local position minus a world position. This is not geometrically meaningful, and will give you nonsense values unrelated to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I found another way, which works: calculate differences beetwen vectors and add into _stepsPointer.transform.localPosition. But I still don't know why adding vectors works fine, while _stepsPointer.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x, y = 1, z) not working, Y value is not equal 1.